# How to obtain an approximate function for SmoothHistogram3D?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, histograms

I have a random distribution of points in the $x\!-\!y$ plane. I can obtain a graphical representation of the probability distribution function using `SmoothHistogram3D`. Now I need to use this in another calculation. To do this I need a function that approximates `SmoothHistogram3D`.

Could you please tell me how to do it?

Comment: Look up `SmoothKernelDistribution[]`.

Comment: That was a brilliant suggestion J.M. I am over the moon. I tested it with NIntegrate by generating a PDF and it worked superbly. All the best. Eitan

Comment: @J.M. this should be an answer

Answer (score 5):

At Vitaliy's behest:

You want the distribution `SmoothKernelDistribution[]`, which can be treated like any other distribution by feeding it into `PDF[]`, `CDF[]`...

Here's a comparison for reference:

```
BlockRandom[SeedRandom[197, Method -> "MersenneTwister"]; (* for reproducibility *)
            data = RandomVariate[BinormalDistribution[.75], 25]];

dist = SmoothKernelDistribution[data, "StandardGaussian", "Gaussian"];
{DensityPlot[PDF[dist, {x, y}], {x, -3.5, 3.8}, {y, -3.9, 4.2}, Mesh -> Automatic,
             MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}], 
 SmoothDensityHistogram[data, {"StandardGaussian", "Gaussian"}, "PDF"]} // GraphicsRow
```

[image: smooth histogram comparison]

Comment: I appreciate that you include the bandwidth and kernel to show how they map from one function to the other.

Comment: I take the extra mile whenever feasible... :)