# Extract Density values from a Smooth density plot

Tags: plotting

I have a SmoothDensityPlot[] of a set of about 10^5 x,y points (`data21fps`) like this

```
SmoothDensityHistogram[data21fps,
 PlotRange -> {{0, 200}, {0, 200}}]
```

[image: Time differences]

I would like to get a the density value of each point of the plot.
I have seen this post [Obtain data points from a density plot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/54505/obtain-data-points-from-a-density-plot) but I have been testing `Reap[]` and `Sow[]` but the Graphics object is different and I do not know how to get the values of the plot.

Thank you very much for the help

**EDIT**

Testing the comments to this question I have tested my dataset

```
D = SmoothKernelDistribution[data21fps]
DensityPlot[PDF[D, {x, y}], {x, 0, 200}, {y, 0, 200}, 
 ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors"]
```

obtaining the following plot

[image: New figure]

However, the graduation is different than in the original `SmoothDensityHistogram[]`. I have tried options of `SmoothKernelDistribution` like ÌnterpolationPoints`,`MaxRecursion`, and`PerformanceGoal`but the results still are different of the original`SmoothDensityPlot`.

Comment: Please have a look at the documentation, specifically in the section "Properties and relations". There you will find an example that shows how `SmoothDensityPlot` is nothing but `DensityPlot` applied to `SmoothKernelDistribution`. i.e., if you want the data, use `SmoothKernelDistribution`.

Comment: @C.E. Thank you, that is what I need it. Can I ask you how to get the absolute values for each point instead of the kernel density estimation?

Comment: If `d` is what `SmoothKernelDistribution` returns, then you can use either `PDF[d, {x, y}]` for the probability density, or `CDF[d, {x,y}]` for the cumulative distribution value at `{x,y}`. The value using `PDF` is what `SmoothDensityPlot` shows you.

Comment: @C.E. I have edited the post with the plot using `SmoothKernelDistribution[]` but the result is not the same

Comment: You might want to see [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/24140) as guide in showing how the functions are related.

Comment: Thank you @J.M., but, how could I get the default parameters of `bandwidth` and `kernel` of SmoothDensityHistogram?

Comment: @user1993416 You can specify the bandwidth selection method and the kernel. They are listed in the documentation under "Details and Options" – so try that and see if you can figure out what settings `SmoothDensityPlot` uses.